# Docker + mysql + php + Symfony, error during connecting to mysql

Tags: mysql, symfony, docker

I'm trying to set up my docker with php app (Symfony 3).

Everything seems to be fine but, Symfony can't connect to mysql.

I have the error:

> Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException: "An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver"

My `docker-compose.yaml` file is:

```
version: '3'
    services:
      app:
        image: car-rental
        ports: 
          - "8888:80"
        links:
          - php
          - db 
        volumes:
          - ./.code:/var/www/html
        depends_on:
          - db
      php:
        image: php:7.1-fpm
        volumes:
          - ./.code:/var/www/html  
      db:
        image: mysql:5.7
        volumes:
          - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
        restart: always
        environment:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
          MYSQL_DATABASE: rental

    volumes:
      mysql-data:
```

Comment: if it works pls accept it @bielu000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mention on the docker hub of php you can see
by default it contain only redis redis xdebug is enabled.

> Some extensions are not provided with the PHP source, but are instead
>   available through PECL. To install a PECL extension, use pecl install
>   to download and compile it, then use docker-php-ext-enable to enable
>   it.

https://hub.docker.com/_/php/

You can use the same docker compose file just run a command on container boot up

```
  php:

image: php:7.1-fpm
command:docker-php-ext-install mysqli
volumes:
  - ./.code:/var/www/html
```

Ater installation you can check

```
php -m
```

These are default modules in the latest docker images that you pulled.

```
    Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
fileinfo
filter
ftp
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mysqlnd
openssl
pcre
PDO
pdo_sqlite
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
SPL
sqlite3
standard
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
zlib
```

Answer (score 1):

This error (`could not find driver`) means, that your PHP doesn't have `pdo_mysql` module loaded. 
You need to enable it or install first if it's not installed yet.

Comment: It seems you to right, but I'm using already built php7.1-fpm container(as you can see in my docker-compose), so I cant install pdo by myself. 
Did I should create php7.1 container by my own Dockefile, where I can place instruction to install pdo driver?